# dell latitude e6540 e port plus ii network adapter not working

Tags: networking, network-adapter, dell-latitude

I own a **Dell latitude e6540 and a E-port plus II**dell latitude e6540 e port plus ii network adapter does not work.
What is happening is that, the network adapter for the port replicator is not working.
If I plug the network cable straight to the laptop it works, but connecting it while the laptop is in the E-port Plus II, it does not work.

Does some one have any ideia of what is happening.

And just to make it clear it is the second E-port plus II having the same problem the first one was replaced by Dell, but it still.

And sorry about my english I'm not a native english speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I would suggest updating your systems BIOS to the latest available on the Dell support site. If the BIOS update has no effect make sure the Ethernet, Gigabit controller driver is also updated.

Should the problem persist after these updates I recommend contacting Dells technical support again and referencing Dell internal knowledge base article **SLN293951**. It’s possible your system will require a motherboard replacement and this article outlines the process for Dells techs on this systems.

**#IWork4Dell**

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the adapter speed in Windows 7 to 100 Mbit for the docking station connection to work. With it set to auto negotiate, it would not work, and the adapter could not be set to 1 Gbit. We have a Brocade ICX6450 gigabit switch on the other end of the connection. I haven't tried yet to set the port speed on the switch to 1 Gbit. Maybe that would work. We also have Lenovo laptops with port replicators, and those are for sure limited to 100 Mbit, even though the laptops can do 1 Gbit.

Comment: turns out this WAS my issue. After trying all other options, including a new dock, it was the "Speed & Duplex" setting on my NIC adapter. It was set to "Auto Negotiation" but changing it to 100Mbps Half Duplex activated the card on the dock and now I'm good to go! Thanks Han!